# How to get data from API to wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, api, mvvm

I am trying to get data from my api to wpf. I'm using mvvm pattern. I'm new at that. So, In Model layer i have EmployeeModel and EmployeeService. In EmployeeService i'm trying to make conection and get data. I need to use that function in EmployeeViewModel i think, and bind to treeview. Here is the code that trying to get data. Also should i need to deserialize data? I tried but i get error.

```
public async void GetAllEmployee()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{conURL}/GetEmployee");

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value getted");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("failed");
                }

                //deserialization
                List<EmployeeModel> ls =
                    await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<EmployeeModel>>();
              

                GetAll(ls);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "May server not running");
            }
        }


    }
    public IList<EmployeeModel> GetAll(IList<EmployeeModel> ls)
    {
        return ls; 

    }
```

Comment: You are missing since context here. It's not apparent how view model and model are related i.e. how the flow is. If the view triggers the service request, then the view model would call a method on the model to receive the requested data. If the model just sends the service request on its own, it usually would expose a related event to notify the listening view model that the data is ready. You can optionally piss the result as event data.

Comment: Well, what if i create and add a func in viewmodel and call like that in My service and  add in to above ViewModelFunc(response); ? I couldn't understand your explanation forgive me. This is what you meant ? Thank you for your explanation by the way.

Comment: Your model could have a class `EmployeRepository` which has a method `GetAllEmployees`. This method then uses the service to obtain a collection of employee entities. In general, your view model should not know the service or use it directly.

Comment: Try being more specific, "i get error" doesn't tell us much.